# Imprimir uma soma na view

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

No ***MySQL WorkBench*** o resultado sai, mas como imprimir na View?

> ErrorException Array to string conversion

```
public function listadepontos()
{
    $id = auth()->user()->id;
    $somas = DB::SELECT("select SUM(pontuacao) FROM palpite WHERE id_u = '$id' ");
    return view('pontuacao')->with('somas', $somas);
}
```

Arquivo pontuacao.php

```
<strong> Sua Pontuação é: <?php echo $somas;?>

</strong>
```

Funcionou assim:

```
@foreach($somas as $s)
  <h4><strong> Sua Pontuação é: {{ $s }}   </strong></h4>
@endforeach
```

*Somente uma vez apareceu a pontuação, porém não acho que seja o jeito correto o código.*

Comment: View seria a página HTML?

Comment: View seria a página HTML? .php html quero imprimir a soma em um "echo"

Comment: O `Laravel` usa o `Blade Engine` para trabalhar com `templates`.

Comment: pode ser em blade tamplate também!

Comment: faz um `var_dump($somas);` ao invés de `echo`

Comment: tem como exemplificar?array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[218]
      public 'soma' => string '8' (length=1)

Gostaria que fosse impresso somente assim "Sua pontuação é: 8 "...

Comment: A linha `$somas = DB::SELECT` está retornando um `array`, então para que você imprimia ela na *View* você deve alterar a linha `view('pontuacao')->with('somas', $somas);` para `view('pontuacao')->with('somas', $somas[0]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos de acordo com a [documentação de execução de SQL puras do](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#running-queries) [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) que diz que o retorno de um [DB::select](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#running-queries) é um array de `stdClass`, (*na documentação trecho em inglês:* **`The select method will always return an array of results. Each result within the array will be a PHP  StdClass object, allowing you to access the values of the results:`**), então os dados da variável `$somas` seria na verdade isso um `array` e na sua primeira posição um `stdClass`. No `Controller` no método de retorno, faça essa alteração na [sql](/questions/tagged/sql):

```
$sql = "select SUM(pontuacao) as p FROM palpite WHERE id_u=?"
$somas = DB::select($sql, [$id]);
return view('pontuacao')->with('somas', $somas[0]->p);
```

e consequentemente na `View` somente:

```
{{$somas}}
```

***Observação:*** *tente enviar para a sua `View` somente o que precisa exibir*.

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Running Raw SQL Queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#running-queries)
- [Laravel: Database](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database)

Answer (score 0):

O `Laravel` usa o `Blade Engine` para trabalhar com `templates`. O seu problema é que o seu retorno esta sendo um `objeto`, veja o que diz a [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#running-queries) sobre o método `select`, para imprimir leia a [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#loops) sobre `loops`.

> O método *select* sempre retornará uma série de resultados. Cada resultado dentro da matriz será um objeto *PHP StdClass*, permitindo que você acesse os valores dos resultados. ( Tradução livre )

Então é só fazer *loop* na *View*

```
@foreach ($somas as $soma)
    <p>{{ $soma }}</p>
@endforeach
```

> **Obs**: Ao responder a pergunta eu tinha colocado o código acima, depois tirei, por pensar que estava errada pois não havia feito teste, antes de negativar consulte o histórico de edições.

Outra forma de retornar, sem precisar fazer *loops*, é alterar a linha:

```
return view('pontuacao')->with('somas', $somas);
```

Para:

```
return view('pontuacao')->with('somas', $somas[0]['soma']);
```

E deixar na *View*

```
{{ $somas }}
```

Comment: E como pego ela lá na pontuacao.blade.php?

Comment: Do mesmo modo como estava antes `echo $somas;`

Comment: dá erro na linha da return view('pontuacao')->with('somas', $somas->soma);
ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object
in PlayersController.php (line 30)

Comment: altera para `$somas[0]` ou `$somas['soma']` é que aonde estou nem como testar.

Comment: FatalErrorException
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

<?php echo $somas[0];?>

Comment: vou testar aqui e já te retorno

Comment: acho que você entendeu errado, quando eu falei para alterar `$somas[0]` ou `$somas['soma']` foi na linha `return view('pontuacao')->with('somas', $somas[0]);` e não no `echo $somas;` e echo deixa normal ou pode alterar para `{{ $somas }}`.

Comment: return view('pontuacao')->with('somas', $somas[0]);

na view
< p >Sua Pontuação é: {{ $somas }} < p >

Comment: ErrorException
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: C:\wamp64\www\Jogos\resources\views\pontuacao.blade.php)
in helpers.php (line 547)
at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), 1)
in PhpEngine.php (line 44)

Comment: @foreach($somas as $s)
      <h4><strong> Sua Pontuação é: {{ $s }}   </strong></h4><br>
@endforeach
asim dá certo... como tem uma só... mas é meio errado ne?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66374/discussion-between-wellingthon-m-de-souza-and-dan-even).

Comment: @DanEven eu tinha colocado assim na resposta primeiro, ai achei que estava errado e tirei, vou colocar novamente e vou deixar esse outro aqui, porque sei que funciona também, só não consegui ainda saber onde estou errando rs.